# Having a phone with no call log

Tags: call-history

There are a lot of questions asking about unlimited call log. I have the exact opposite problem: I want no call log at all in the software.

Even with a phone with "pocket detection" and a complicated swipe pattern, I still happen to randomly call a number who called me previously and that I do not want to call (clients who do not see my number when they call me : I do not want them to have *my* number). For instance because of inadvertent manipulation, drop of water on the screen making the touch detection put my finger where it isn't, etc...

I do not care about privacy issues, I just do not want to have any way to reach a call log with phone numbers from the UI.

Is there any way to achieve that with android ? Maybe with a third-party phone app ?

Comment: Call logs are integral to phone apps and are considered essential, not withstanding your concerns. Therefore, it's unlikely to find an app that can do this // Use  of [tag:automation] tools to delete call records is an option, other being you write your own app for this

Comment: In line with automation suggestion, you can try [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) //[Set up a macro like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs16P.png), make and save it. I haven't tested it but it should work

Comment: Thanks, that macrodroid solution looks like it's enough for me

Comment: Good. You can try that and if that works for you either post an answer yourself or ask me